# Json result format in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to read the text file into json. i have a text file with three lines.
 While i tried to read using json .It returns all the 3 lines into one string.

Here is my code for your reference :

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        bool result = false;
        StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength == 0)
                throw new Exception("Zero length file!");
            else
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads"), fileName);

                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads"), fileName)))
                    {
                        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            strbuild.AppendFormat(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = strbuild.ToString()
        };
    }
```

**My Result is  :**

"HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*1       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                                    12345678I                     22 DEC 1960SPO                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016           HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*2       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816AREBECCA SIOW SIQIN                                                                                  S1234567E                     04 FEB 1995C O                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016           HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*3       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ASAMANTHA SIOW SIHUI                                                                                 S1234567J                     18 NOV 1993C O                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016           "

**My Text File is :**

line 1:
HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*1       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                                    12345678I                     22 DEC 1960SPO                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016

line 2 :

HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*2       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816AREBECCA SIOW SIQIN                                                                                  S1234567E                     04 FEB 1995C O                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016

Line 3:
HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*3       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H-000001              15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ASAMANTHA SIOW SIHUI                                                                                 S1234567J                     18 NOV 1993C O                                       F-                                                                                                                                                                                                       15 JUL 201615 JUL 2016

So how can i show the json result with 3 (String) lines ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: instead of using `streadreader` you can use `File.ReadAllText` and then split the lines by `\r,\n` and form the object and serialize it to JSON

Comment: Use a `List<string>` instead of `StringBuilder` and add each line to the collection, then return the collection

Comment: Can you explain it with example,please @StephenMuecke. i didn't understand "add each line to the collection"

Comment: `List<string> lines = new List<string>(); ... while (sr.Peek() >= 0) { lines.Add(sr.ReadLine()); } ... return Json(lines);`

Comment: And its not clear what the point of your `catch` block is for - the value of `result` is already `false` (you never set it to true anywhere, and you never use it anyway). And there is no point in throwing an exception using `throw new Exception("Zero length file!");`

Comment: Thanks, Now i can able to Manage as 3 lines